# Does a reference to an element break when that element is moved or attached?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm new to JS, and still not quite sure how the DOM works. I have a few pointed questions.

If I have a reference to an DOM element, like...

```
var element = document.createElement("DIV");
```

Does that reference stay valid when I...

```
foo.appendChild(element);
```

Or...

```
foo.insertBefore(element, bar);
```

Finally what exactly is stored when I point a DOM node to a variable? Is there a magic ID behind the scenes, or something else? Thanks.

Comment: `Does that reference stay valid when I...` - this couldn't be easier to test yourself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a reference to *anything* in JavaScript, that reference remains valid as long as you have it. This includes DOM objects as well as ordinary JavaScript objects.

Consider this non-DOM example to get the idea:

```
var objects = {
    one: { foo: 'bar' },
    two: { hoo: 'har' }
};

var won = objects.one;
console.log( 'objects:', objects );
console.log( 'won:', won );
delete objects.one;
console.log( 'objects:', objects );
console.log( 'won:', won );
```

If you paste that into the JavaScript console, it will log:

```
objects: Object {one: Object, two: Object}
won: Object {foo: "bar"}
objects: Object {two: Object}
won: Object {foo: "bar"}
```

As you can see, deleting the `one` property from `objects` has no effect on the additional reference stored in the `won` variable.

The same is true of DOM elements. When you create a DOM element and hold a reference to it, that reference—and the object it refers to—won't go away unless you release the reference and there are no other outstanding references to it. For example, this function creates a DOM element but does not preserve any references to it:

```
function silly() {
    var foo = document.createElement('div');
}

silly();
```

Here we create a DOM element and put a reference to it in the `foo` variable. But then the function returns, which destroys that variable and releases its reference to the DOM element. That element is now free to be garbage collected at any later time.

That's different from your example, where you actually keep a variable around that holds the reference.

How does this work behind the scenes? Well, that depends on the particular JavaScript engine. Most JavaScript engines are written in C or C++ and use pointers combined with garbage collection or similar techniques. There isn't usually some kind of magic ID lookup to find the DOM element when you have a reference to it; it's more like a direct pointer reference in C. One thing points directly to another, in a fairly similar fashion to how a variable "points to" (holds a reference to) an object in JavaScript.

Of course, as @Mics points out (pun intended), the exact details are implementation dependent. It *could* be a magic ID lookup, or just about anything, as long as the behavior of the JavaScript code is as specified.

Comment: In addition, DOM is just an interface spec. If you assign a DOM node to a variable, a variable now stores a *DOM node*. There might be memory reference, index, or magic ID under the curtain, but it's totally implementation area.